# Footer is missing in odoo 8 report

Tags: report, odoo

I am using ubuntu 13.10 (32 bit) and wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1. While printing the reports as pdf in odoo, footer is missing. How could i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. There is a related issue on github:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2907

downgrade the version to 0.12.0 worked for me.

This is what I did:

- downloaded previous version from **(note the underscore in http. Stack overflow only allows me 1 link)**:  h_ttp://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/archive/0.12.0/wkhtmltox-linux-amd64_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz
- unzip the file: tar Jxf wkhtmltox-linux-amd64_0.12.0-03c001d.tar.xz
- replace existing the files in  /usr/local/lib/ and  /usr/local/bin/ folders with the previous version

Now  wkhtmltopdf -V is:

> Name:
>     wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 03c001de254b857f08eba80b62d4b6490ffed41d
>
> License:
>     Copyright (C) 2010 wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage Authors.
>
> License LGPLv3+: GNU Lesser General Public License version 3 or later
>     http://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html. This is free software: you are free to
>     change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
>     law.
>
> Authors:
>     Written by Jan Habermann, Christian Sciberras and Jakob Truelsen. Patches by
>     Mehdi Abbad, Lyes Amazouz, Pascal Bach, Emmanuel Bouthenot, Benoit Garret > > and
>     Mário Silva.
>
> Compiled against wkhtmltopdf patched qt.

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check which version of wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1  is installed in your system 
Enter the Below command From the Terminal some think like

**wkhtmltopdf -V**

that gives us the version and the wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 
if it fine then uninstalled that packages from the terminal and reinstall it again 
other wise install a new one from the below link based on system requirement
[Click To download wkhtmltopdf package hear](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) 
and restart the server and upgrade the **Report Module** and Print the Report

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and the solution with wkhtmltopdf didn't work for me.

What helped me was creating report.url with http://0.0.0.0:8069/ in settings/technical/parameters - as soon as I created this, the footer showed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can check  this [Report formatting not working in Odoo 8 Qweb Reports](http://Report%20formatting%20not%20working%20in%20Odoo%208%20Qweb%20Reports)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue today and the problem was that

> web.base.url

was defined with different value thаn my current port.

Ex: It was 127.0.0.1:8079 and my localhost port for odoo is 8069. After changing the port the issue has gone.